# Dependency Problem in Springboot Micro Services

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, microservices

[image of intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxVWg.png)
java: Annotation processing is not supported for module cycles. Please ensure that all modules from cycle [User, Recharge, Contest] are excluded from annotation processing

I am unable to start my microservices in IntelliJ because it depends on other microservice and others depend on this. please help

Comment: http://gal-levinsky.blogspot.com/2012/04/judgement-day-weapon-for-circular.html follow this, hope it helps

Comment: this was helpful but i had to re design entire application and it worked that way. thanks :)

Comment: whenever cyclic dependency occurs, in 98 % of cases we must need to re-design.

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE

File Menu ---> Analyze ---> Module Dependencies or Analyze Module Dependencies..

it will show you a list of projects with cyclic dependencies

This feature helps you to find the problem.